# A question about the category of co-elements

Tags: category-theory

The **category of elements** of a $K: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mbox{Set}$, denoted by $1\downarrow K$ is defined to be a category which has as objects arrows of the form $d: * \rightarrow Kd$ i.e. the collection of pairs $\left(d,x\right)$ with $x: \mathcal{D}$ and $x \in Kd$. This category is equipped with the forgetful $\left(d,x\right)\mapsto d: 1\downarrow K \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ and pervades basic category theory for:

- It has an initial object, precisely when $K$ is representable.
- It appears in coyoneda lemma, i.e. the following naturallity where $Q$ is the forgetful functor: $$Nat \left(K,\mathcal{D}\left(a,-\right)\right)\cong Nat\left(a,Q\right)$$
- Whether $K$ is representable or not, it is naturally equivalant to a colimit of a diagram of representable functors, where the diagram is given by the category of elements.

My question is concerned with the category of **co-elements** of $K:\mathcal{D}\rightarrow Set$, which has as objects $\left(X,f\right)$ where $X:\mathcal{D}$ and $f:KX\rightarrow 2$ i.e. the comma category $K \downarrow 2$. Note, that this is dual in the sense that $2$ is a co-generator for $Set$, in contrast with $1$ which is a generator. This construction is also equipped with a forgetful functor $\left(X,f\right)\mapsto X:K\downarrow 2 \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$, which we denote by $P$.

> What are the analogous applications of the category of co-elements of $K$? For instance, is it true that:
>
> - It has an terminal object, precisely when $K$ is co-representable (naturally equivalant to $\mathcal{D}\left(-,r\right)$) or:
> - Whether $K$ is representable or not, it is naturally equivalant to a limit of a diagram of representable functors, where the diagram is given by the category of co-elements?

Thanks

Comment: Wait, what is $r$ in $r\in Kd$?

Comment: What have you tried to answer your questions? It's No in each case. I doubt that this category of co-elements is useful at all.

Comment: Is $K$ a contravariant functor?